# Calculus derivative, Am I missing something?

Tags: calculus

what is the derivative of

$$ (x-a)^2 +y^2 = a^2 $$

My answer was $$ dy/dx = (2a-x)/y $$

But the correct answer was $$ (a-x)/y $$

My steps :

$$ 2(x-a) *1 + 2y * dy/dx = 2a $$
$$ 2x - 2a + 2y * dy/dx = 2a $$ 
solve for $$ dy/dx $$

Comment: *Hint*: Your first step is wrong $d(a^2)/dx = 0 \ne 2a$, as $a$ does not depend on $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a$ is a constant and we know that the derivative of a constant is $0$. So you should get: $$2x-2a+2y\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=0\implies \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\dfrac{a-x}y.$$

Answer (score 2):

See that **Derivative of a constant is $0$**

You should have :

$2(x-a)+ (2y)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ and rest follows easily...